# Conditional Validations in Ruby while using ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I'm fairly new to Ruby, so I'm hoping I just missed something obvious. I have an application with a form that goes through validation using something like this...

```
module FormValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do

    validates :field_1, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }
    validates :field_2, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }
    validate :field_sec, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }

    def field_sec
      (*some custom stuff*)
    end
```

...and so on, which works fine.

I now have a new type of form that uses the same model and database structure, but with a bit set to something different. It also undergoes a completely different validation process. I've been trying to find a way so make the validation calls conditional, something like...

```
included do

  validate :form_switch, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }

  def form_switch
    #This uses a method I defined in the model to tell which form is active
    if is_special_form == true
      validates :field_245, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }
      validates :field_432, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }
    else
      validates :field_1, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }
      validates :field_2, :if => lambda { self.stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY] }
    end
  end
```

...but the "validates" throw an error when placed inside of a method.

I also toyed with the idea of having two separate validation script files that get included into my form model, but since the process is executed with a simple ".valid?" method, I'm not sure how to distinguish between the scripts on that level either.

Is there a way to switch between two (or more) sets of validations using a single model?

Answer (score 1):

You could do all validations conditional. I don't think it's necessary to nest everything so deep. Since the contents of included block will be executed in the context of your model class, this should work:

```
included do
  validates :field_245, :if => :validate_field_245?
  validates :field_432, :if => :validate_field_432?
  validates :field_1, :if => :validate_field_1?
  validates :field_2, :if => :validate_field_2?

  def validate_field_245?
    is_special_form && stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY]
  end

  def validate_field_432?
    is_special_form && stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY]
  end

  def validate_field_1?
    !is_special_form && stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY]
  end

  def validate_field_2?
    !is_special_form && stage == APPLICATION_STAGE[:DATA_ENTRY]
  end
end
```

Once you see yourself using different validations conditionally, it's good time to consider [using form objects](http://trailblazer.to/gems/reform/) to handle validation logic. [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) libraries make it easy.

Comment: Nice idea. At that point though, I might be able to simplify it by making two methods (special and !special) instead of many, since the content is not dependent on anything field-specific. I'll post more after I try it out.